# Host Internal Site Using IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

I am trying to set-up a test IIS page so that I can test out how code will function before pushing it to our production environment.  I have the below settings in place
**Contents of webconfig**

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> 
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="Home.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
```

And my **BINDINGS** are set-up like so

> Type: http
>   Host Name: 192.168.5.14
>   Port: 81
>   IP: *

However, if anytime I attempt to navigate to `http:192.168.5.14:81` I get an error of

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>
> The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I am confused on this, as I thought I set the default page in my webconfig above, and secondly I do not want to enable directory browsing as I only want to be able to navigate to the IP and have my aspx project launch.

What am I missing to get this set-up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as, the port 81 is not allowed. Solution: Go to Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings 
Select Inbound Rules
1) Click on New Rule
2) Select Rule Type to Port. Click Next
3) Select TCP and specific port enter the 81
4) Next, choose Allow the connection
5) Choose appropriately the Domain, Private, and public
6) Provide the name to this port such as website name

Try accessing the site, should work.

Comment: If I try to access it now, I get a 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. Error message.  Still trying to access the site by http:192.168.5.14:81  And If I look under Edit Perms --> Security both myself and IIS_IUSRS are granted access.

Answer (score 0):

The default port for http is 80. But you have configured it in 81 so that the software or hardware firewall will surely block your access. So that you may try to do the above answer or else disable the firewall temporarily to check it is blocking or not, you can also check it through the firefox browser's console box. If it isn't the problem then check the hosted server.